# Image clustering using predefined ranges - Python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to python language. My objective here is to classify the images based on predefined range.

1. I have three image data viz. Rainfall, Soil Moisture and Wilting Point and all are in float type.
2. I have predefined range for cultivable land say. RF < 5mm, Soil Moist  between 8 to 16, and Wilting pt between 2 to 4.
3. i need to classify the above mentioned data with these predefined ranges into very good (if three conditions satisfied), medium (any of two conditions satisfied) low (one condition satisfied) and not useful (nothing is satisfied)

Kindly help me out to get an classified out. Thank u in advance

I have already tried with conditional statement approach but i dint pass through it. lot of errors.

Comment: Hi Aravind and welcome to Stack Overflow! In order to increase the chances of getting a useful answer, I suggest you take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What do you have so far? Please add the code you're struggling with.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a list of vectors, and each vector dimension should be 3. I will post you an example of how i would do it.

```
data = [[1.0, 7.0, 1.0], [5.0, 9.0, 2.0], [6.0, 15.0, 4.0]] #[RF, Soil Moist, Wilting pt]
results = []
for vector in data:
    checks = [False, False, False]
    if(vector[0]<5.0):
        checks[0]=True
    if(vector[1]>=8.0 and vector[1]<=16.0):
        checks[1]=True
    if(vector[2]>=2.0 and vector[2]<=4.0):
        checks[2]=True

    #Decision
    num_trues = sum(checks)
    results.append(num_trues)

print(num_trues)
```

Here the results list is a list of integers, and each value corresponds to the same vector position in data.

Note that your categorical here will be numeric:
 - 0, any condition satisfied
 - 1, one condition satisfied
 - 2, two conditions satisfied
 - 3, three conditions satisfied

Hope it helps!